# Change Preference value from non-PreferenceActivity/Fragment

Tags: android, android-preferences

So to change the value programatically you will usually do `findPreference("my_key")` and get the preference's reference to change the value.

What about doing it programatically not in `PreferenceActivity` or `PreferenceFragment` but on a simple `Activity` or `Fragment`?

is it possible to get a `Preference` reference (if so, how)? or should I do it the old school way getting a `SharedPreference` reference, and using `Editor`?

Answer (score 1):

> So to change the value programatically you will usually do findPreference("my_key") and get the preference's reference to change the value.

That is solely for changing the value as is represented in the preference UI. The fact that it happens to perhaps update the persisted value is a side effect, not the purpose.

> is it possible to get a Preference reference

No.

> or should I do it the old school way getting a SharedPreference reference, and using Editor?

Yes.

Comment: can you please update the answer with an example? because I can not get the value of an existing preference in this way - `getSharedPreferences(APP.PREFS_NAME, 0).getString("my_key", "empty"));` I got back "empty"

Comment: @HiB: Your comment is not related to this question. If you are getting `"empty"`, then there is no preference named `"my_key"` in that `SharedPreferences` file. You may wish to open up your own Stack Overflow question where you provide more details.

Comment: thanks, I [have written one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837236/how-to-change-preference-value-from-non-preferenceactivity-fragment)